# Automation Testing - Ensuring the save actually happened

Tags: automation, automated-tests

Let us say I have a form that has 20 different fields on it with all control types: text box, grid, text area, spinner, etc.

I have an excel sheet where I read the data from , load it onto a dataset and then use it to key-in the form. Once after my script has filled in the values on the form, I click on a button called Save - this button saves the data to DB and just stays on the screen with whatever values I have entered.

**Here comes the problem:** There was an issue reported by Manual testers that of all the 20 fields, just 2 fields did not retain the value they entered and saved. Those two fields for some reason is cleared upon saving. Not only they are cleared from the UI but also the values are not saved in the DB. This is clearly a valid bug.

My script could not find this because I do not have any logic coded to check whether the values are all there on the form / DB or not.. I mean after saving. I do not think anyone usually does that either. We all just perform data entry and save the record. Did it really save or not? Do we check that in automation?

**So, my question is -** how do one usually ensure the values key-in by a script is actually saved?

I mean the purpose of automation is not just data entry but also to have the intelligence to say whether the Save functionality happened successfully or not. How can I code this?

I gave it a lot of thought. I came up with this:

> I can capture the screenshot of the screen after clicking of the Save
>   button. The manual testers will have to see the screenshot to find out
>   if any field values are missing or not.

I cannot think of any other solution. Any idea, anyone? How have other automation engineers have handled this scenario?

Comment: Are you using some sort of test harness that provides the ability to perform assertions?

Comment: No I'm not. My automation is done using MS VS Coded UI. The application is a WPF based Windows Application. Just giving the information if that helps at all to guide further. Thanks!

Comment: Never used Coded UI, but it looks like it has assertions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404081.aspx

Comment: Oh, assertions! Are you telling me to assert all the 20 fields to see whether the value I entered is there or not? Isn't that a overhead? I mean when I automate a bigger form with more fields, I'll have assert for that many fields to check if the value my script entered is retained. Is that the right way to do this?

Comment: I've one other thought - The fields on a WPF form are basically nothing but the attributes of a class, right? Is there something a developer can do to give access to the object with values of all those properties? I can just cross check it with the source I've used to enter those values into those fields. This definitely isn't a UI/Functional automation but then I will atleast be able to validate if the save actually worked or not.